# Using jquery, how to populate my table rows with matching pictures using img src="javascript:?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Consider I have a table, like below, that I am trying to populate with many jpegs for each row, like say `BillSmith.jpg` and `NancyClinton.jpg`.

### Example Table to be populated with pics:

**NY | Smith, Bill** *(trying to put `'BillSmith.jpg'` here)*
**NY | Clinton, Nancy** *(trying to put `'NancyClinton.jpg'` here)*

I am confused with what to put after this part `<img src="javascript:` in the 2nd to last line of the below code snippet.

```
$("#html_table tbody td:nth-child(2)").each(function(){
        var the_name = $(this).html();

        // Creates the string of file names ( BillSmith.jpg ) matching the file names of jpeg pics

        var nameList = the_name.split(",");
        var firstLast = nameList[1] + nameList[0];
        var source_foto = "staff_jpegs/"+firstLast+".jpg";

        $(this).html( the_name +'<br><div class="fotos" style="text-align:center"><img src="javascript:source_foto" height="80" width="80"/></div>');
        });
```

The above code doesnt work because I am assuming a function not a variable can only be after `javascript:` .

Looking the easy way to get many fotos into their corresponding table rows using more or less this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#html_table tbody td:nth-child(2)").each(function(){
        var the_name = $(this).html();

        // Creates the string of file names ( BillSmith.jpg ) matching the file names of jpeg pics

        var nameList = the_name.split(", ");
        var firstLast = nameList[1] + nameList[0];
        var source_foto = "staff_jpegs/"+firstLast+".jpg";

        $(this).html( the_name +'<br><div class="fotos" style="text-align:center"><img src="'+source_foto+'" height="80" width="80"/></div>');
        });
```

You don't need the javascript: you can just use the variable name.  Also, your split should be on ", " and not just ","

Answer (score 1):

Since you've used string concatenation it means you know it exists, but why can't you use it in the second instance?

```
$(this).html( the_name +'<br><div class="fotos" style="text-align:center"><img src="' + source_foto + '" height="80" width="80"/></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).html( the_name +'<br><div class="fotos" style="text-align:center"><img src="'+ source_foto +'" height="80" width="80"/></div>');
```